# preg_replace mail.ru redirect

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть текст битком набитый вот такими ссылками. Нужно как-то выудить из него прямой url и записать его на место редиректа. Просьба помочь с составлением регулярки!

```
<a href="http://win.mail.ru/cgi-bin/link?check=1&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fredirect.subscribe.ru%2Flaw.russia.review.consdailyrus%2C2215%2F20110128105418%2Fn%2Fm17587277%2F-%2Fmy.consultant.ru%2Fcabinet%2F%3Fmode%3Dstat%3Bclick%3Bd%3D2011-01-27%3Br%3Dfd%3Bs%3Dsubscribe%3Bdst%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.consultant.ru%252Flaw%252Freview%252Flink%252F%253Fid%253D961912">О федеральной целевой программе</a>
```

**Добавлено**.

Спасибо! Удалось почить конечную ссылку без редиректов, дописав вот такое:

```
foreach($res[1] as $n => $link)
    if (!empty($res[2][$n])) {
        $url = urldecode($res[2][$n]);
        if ( (preg_match('/redirect.subscribe.ru/is', $url)) > 0 ) {
            parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $url);
            $url = $url['mode'];
            $l=strpos($url, 'dst=');
            $url = str_split($url,$l+4);
            $result = $url[1].$url[2];
        } else {
            $result = $url;
        }

        $text = str_replace($link, $result, $text);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?
$text = '<a href="http://win.mail.ru/cgi-bin/link?check=1&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fredirect.subscribe.ru%2Flaw.russia.review.consdailyrus%2C2215%2F20110128105418%2Fn%2Fm17587277%2F-%2Fmy.consultant.ru%2Fcabinet%2F%3Fmode%3Dstat%3Bclick%3Bd%3D2011-01-27%3Br%3Dfd%3Bs%3Dsubscribe%3Bdst%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.consultant.ru%252Flaw%252Freview%252Flink%252F%253Fid%253D961912">О федеральной целевой программе</a>
<a href="http://win.mail.ru/cgi-bin/link?check=1&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fredirect.subscribe.ru%2Flaw.russia.review.consdailyrus%2C2215%2F20110128105418%2Fn%2Fm17587277%2F-%2Fmy.consultant.ru%2Fcabinet%2F%3Fmode%3Dstat%3Bclick%3Bd%3D2011-01-27%3Br%3Dfd%3Bs%3Dsubscribe%3Bdst%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.consultant.ru%252Flaw%252Freview%252Flink%252F%253Fid%253D961912123">О федеральной целевой программе 123</a>';

echo '<h3>До</h3>';
echo '<hr />';
echo $text;
echo '<hr />';

$exp = '/<a.*href="(http.*url=([^"]+))"[^>]*>/i';    
$res = $res2 = array();
preg_match_all($exp, $text, $res);
if (!empty($res[1]))
  foreach($res[1] as $n => $link)
    if (!empty($res[2][$n]))
      $text = str_replace($link, urldecode($res[2][$n]), $text);

echo '<h3>После</h3>';
echo '<hr />';
echo $text;
echo '<hr />';
?>
```

Единственное - редиректов в ссылке таки 2 (mail.ru + subscribe.ru) и второй сложнее выловить. Но до первого код выше обрабатывает.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, в данном случае проще воспользоваться [xml парсером](http://php.net/simplexml).

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($text);

// пробегаемся по всем ссылкам с атрибутом href
foreach ($xml->xpath('//a[@href]') as $a) {

    // пропускаем ссылки без query
    if ( !($query = parse_url($a['href'], PHP_URL_QUERY)) ) {
        continue;
    }

    // парсим query, значения будут уже декодированны
    parse_str($query, $params);

    // меняем атрибут на соответсувующий параметр, если есть 
    if (isset($params['url'])) {
        $a['href'] = $params['url'];
    }
}

var_dump($xml->asXML());
```

UPD. Если уж очень хочется именно по регулярке заменить, то лучше всего воспользоваться [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback)

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/(<a\b[^>]+href=)(\S+)\b([^>]*>)/i', function($m) {

        $url = htmlspecialchars_decode(trim($m[2], '"\''));
        if ( !($query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY)) ) {
            return $m[0];
        }

        parse_str($query, $params);
        if (!isset($params['url'])) {
            return $m[0];
        }

        $url = $params['url'];
        $parts = parse_url($url);
        if ($parts['host'] !== 'redirect.subscribe.ru') {
            return $m[1].$url.$m[3];
        }

        parse_str($parts['query'], $params);
        if (!isset($params['mode']) || !preg_match('/;dst=(.+)/', $params['mode'], $n)) {
            return $m[1].$url.$m[3];
        }

        return $m[1].$n[1].$m[3];
}, $text);
```

Comment: Увы, не варсит.

Comment: Что значит "не варсит"?

Comment: Большинство HTML-документов не являются XML-документами, так что XML-парсеры ничего не могут пропарсить.

Comment: Современные XML-парсеры умеют парсить HTML. Т.н. код выше без проблем отрабатывает со строкой ТС. Кроме того, всегда можно воспользоваться [DOM][1]

  [1]: http://ru.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: Чтобы получить DOM-дерево документа, его надо пропарсить. "Современные XML-парсеры умеют парсить HTML" - в таком случае, они таковыми не являются, а являются HTML-парсерами. Поскольку разница между HTML и XML очень существенна.

Comment: >  в таком случае, они таковыми не являются, а являются HTML-парсерами

Согласен, некорректно выразился: нужно воспользоваться html-парсером. Сути это не меняет. libxml2 это позволяет сделать, simplexml и dom, соответственно, тоже. Так в чем-же тогда проблема?

Comment: В целом, идея с парсером настолько верна, насколько хорошо работает сам парсер и от того, насколько хороши сами страницы, которые парсятся.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярными выражениями можно искать только саму ссылку. Ссылку из url-параметра надо декодировать с помощью [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Соответствующее регулярное выражение составьте на основе уже готовых. Например, из [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/). Или на основании [множества других](https://encrypted.google.com/webhp#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=URL+PHP+regexp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f546fe579d97ce08&biw=1436&bih=782).